# How do I prevent both narrowing and late binding?

Tags: vb.net

This might be a dumb question, but I just turned on Option Strict for the first time, and I'm not sure what the best approach is here.

I have a bunch of dynamically created PictureBox controls, and I'm adding event handlers when they're created to handle their paint events. In the paint event, I need to access the ClientRectangle of the PictureBox. Notice that I've changed *sender As Object* to *sender As PictureBox*:

```
Public Sub Example(sender As PictureBox, e As PaintEventArgs)
    AlreadyExistingRectangle = sender.ClientRectangle
    AlreadyExistingRectangle.Inflate(-2, -2)
    ' Draw stuff in AlreadyExistingRectangle
End Sub
```

I need the AlreadyExistingRectangle for various reasons (though I suspect there are better solutions). The reason I'm using *sender as PictureBox* is because my paint events are kind of slow, and I thought it might speed it up, as sender.ClientRectangle would cause late binding otherwise. But now, narrowing occurs, because the delegate sub uses *sender as Object*.

So, is there a simple solution, or should I just allow late binding or narrowing? And if so, which is faster?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you just created a variable within the `Paint` event handler and casted to a `PictureBox`? It'd only be one extra line: `Dim senderPictureBox As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)`.

Comment: The first time I tried that, it threw an exception (I can't remember why), so I assumed that wasn't an option. I just tried it, and it's working swimmingly. It's much smoother now, thanks a lot.

Comment: The only time it would throw an exception is if `sender` _is not_ a `PictureBox`. I'll write an answer so you can mark your question as resolved (that is, unless you still want someone to answer which is fastest out of late binding and narrowing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it'd be best if you created a variable in the `Paint` event handler where you cast `sender` to a `PictureBox`. Then you can wrap the whole thing in a [**`Try/Catch` block**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) to catch the cast exceptions that [**`DirectCast`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx) throws if `sender` *is not* a `PictureBox`.

```
Try
    Dim senderPictureBox As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    'Do your stuff...
Catch ex As InvalidCastException
    'Either do something here or just ignore the error.
End Try
```

Alternatively, since throwing exceptions is costly for your already, as you state it, slow code, you could use [**`TryCast`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8.aspx) which instead of throwing an exception just returns `Nothing` if the cast fails (this is much faster performance-wise).

```
Dim senderPictureBox As PictureBox = TryCast(sender, PictureBox)

If senderPictureBox IsNot Nothing Then
    'Do your stuff...
End If
```

Comment: Thanks again. Is there any point in using TryCast when I know for sure that the sender is a PictureBox? I'm not catching exceptions, and it's working. I read just now that DirectCast is slightly faster.

Comment: @MagnusBakke : As long as the `sender` remains a `PictureBox` not catching exceptions is fine. Though I'm curious where you read that `DirectCast` would be faster than `TryCast`... As far as I know there shouldn't be much of a difference really,

Comment: @MagnusBakke : After testing with the [**`Stopwatch` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) both `DirectCast` and `TryCast` execute in `0.0000004s`, max `0.0000008s`.

Comment: TryCast tests the object first, directCast skips that step

Comment: @MagnusBakke If you hundered 100% sure that neither object of the some other type or null can be in that argument, you can use direct cast

Comment: @T.S. : However they both seem to execute almost equally fast, so the overhead is really not big.